# Amazon.com returns status 503

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get https://www.amazon.com content with Python Requests library. But I got an server error instantly. Here is the code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com')
print(response)
```

And this code returns **<Response [503]>**. Anyone can tell me why is this happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon requires, that you specify `User-Agent` HTTP header to return 200 response:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com', headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Prints:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: By the way can you tell me is there any "best" headers to use? Or headers doesn't mean much since we already got the access?

Comment: @KoboldMines You can use standard browser headers. For example open Chrome/Firefox developer tools -> Network tab, make a request to `amazon.com` and look at the request headers

Comment: @KoboldMines The more you can make the request appear like a normal browser, the easier it will be when reading big sites using an http library (although you might violate TOS on those sites by doing so). There are more nuanced differences between requests sent by browsers versus `requests` than just the user-agent string, so be aware of that if some other site still throws a mysterious error, even with a proper user string set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla 5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com', headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not put the code from which you want the info.
The code should be like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com')
print(response.content)
```

also you can use `json`, `status_code` or `text` in place of `content`

Comment: i am new here pls cooperate

Comment: Hi Pushpak. I am working on scraping Amazon page, but I have some issues with cookies and headers. Do you know anything about this topic?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @PushpakBarhate.  Please take the [tour] and read [answer] to learn about how the site works.